# Office 365 - Connecting to Exchange using PowerShell WinRM issues

Tags: powershell, office365

I am trying to connect to my O365 Exchange Online but getting WinRM error messages when doing so.

```
$user = "user@domain.co.uk"
$cred = Get-Credential -Credential $user

$exchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri "https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/" -Credential $cred -Authentication "Basic" -AllowRedirection
```

when running that I get the following error message:

```
> New-PSSession : [outlook.office365.com] Connecting to remote server
> outlook.office365.com failed with the following error message : The
> WinRM client cannot process the request. Basic authentication is
> currently disabled in  the client configuration. Change the client
> configuration and try the request again. For more information, see the
> about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At line:1 char:20
> + $exchangeSession = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -Connecti ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession],
> PSRemotingTransportException
>     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2144108321,PSSessionOpenFailed
```

I have looked online around WinRM and basic authentication.
I have enabled basic authentication through GPO but this hasn't done much.

Any information would be great.

Thanks

Comment: It is worth nothing that I can connect to the O365 admin portal and SharePoint via Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you have MFA enabled for the admin account - disable that.  Cheers.

Comment: In the case of having Azure MFA enabled : you can use an app password.